# Response status code does not indicate success: 500 in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

Sometimes I get "Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)" but it doesn't always happens, Why does it happen and how can I prevent it? Thank you in Advance

```
try
            {

                    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        Credentials = new
                            NetworkCredential(settings["userp"].ToString(),            settings["usern"].ToString())
                    })
                    {
                        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                        {
                            var result = await client.GetStringAsync(uriSources);
                            string st = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(result);
                        }
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR...", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }}
```

It doesn't happens all the time, but if I run "https://*******.azurewebsites.net/Api/Membership/1" in Chrome it does work... That's why I think there is a problem with my code.

Comment: That's an error from service you're using, so you can't really *do* anything to fix from your phone. You just have to handle it appropriately.

Comment: I am currently working with azure, are there any problems with azure or with the web API?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem isn't with Azure as much as it's with the service your calling

Comment: Contact whoever owns the service you're trying to access? The 500 error is coming from them.

Comment: https://*******.azurewebsites.net/Api/Membership/1 if I run this from chrome it returns me the string I need. That's why I think there is a problem with my code

Comment: Use a program like Fiddler, and see what exactly gets sent to the API when you access it through the browser. Them mimic it on your phone.

Comment: @FergieGauvain System Down is correct. 500 error code only comes from server. Also, just one suggestion, for idempotent get requests, add an additional query param say url+&randomParam=DateTime.Now().ToString().

Windows phone keeps a cache of get request & it might cause you some issue sooner or later. :)